# define alias for specific template method instances

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Assume I have a function which manipulate strings, and which perfectly handle all char types.

```
template<typename CharT>
std::basic_string<CharT> foo_basic_string()
{
   return std::basic_string<CharT, char_traits<CharT>, allocator<CharT> >();
}
```

I want functions `foo_string` and `foo_wstring` to be a version of `foo_basic_string` and return a `std::string` and `std::wstring`, respectively.

One way is

```
std::string foo_string()
{
    return foo_basic_string<char>();
}

std::wstring foo_wstring()
{
    return foo_basic_string<wchar_t>();
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to declare `foo_string` as **actually being the instance** `foo_basic_string<char>`.

Comment: The second and third template argument you pass to `basic_string` is superfluous as those are the default arguments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write

```
auto& foo_string  = foo_basic_string<char>;
auto& foo_wstring = foo_basic_string<wchar_t>;
```

This declares `foo_string` as a reference to function, referring to the specialization of your template.